# Python2 Optparse questions: Multiple help sections, multiple actions per option?

Tags: python-2.7, optparse

I have two questions related to optparse for parsing command line parameters in Python.

1. Is there a way to create sections in the help output?

Example of desired output:

```
Usage: script.py [options]

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -d DB, --database=DB  Specify path to database file
  -p SRC, --path=SRC    Specify path to folder containing data files
  -o OUT, --output=OUT  Specify output path to put processed files

Actions:
  -c, --list-classes    Produce list of available classes from database
  -f CLASS, --list-files=CLASS
                        Product list of files for class CLASS

Output Control:
  -q, --quiet           Do not produce any output
  -v, --verbose         Be more verbose
```

2: Can I cause a parameter to do two things: change one variable in the options to the given value but ALSO change another value to a static constant?

Example:

```
p.add_option("-o","--output",action="store",dest="out",type="string",
             help="Specify output path to put processed files")
p.add_option("-o","--output",action="store_const",dest="action",const="do_processing",
             help="Specify output path to put processed files")
```

I want *both* of the above actions to occur when the option is passed.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: You tagged your question with python-2.7 and optparse.  But optparse is deprecated in favor of argparse in Python 2.7.  Would you consider that?